# joining two tables using CTE

Tags: t-sql, join, reporting-services, common-table-expression

I have two queries return following output: T1 and T2

Now I would like to join both tables on the T1.CMonth and T2.DueMonth fields.

The Final output should be as shown in the png.

The query for T1:

> SELECT        WorkManagementAsset.AssetCategory, CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 120) AS CMonth, 
>                            COUNT(CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 120)) AS Total_Complete
>   FROM            WorkManagementAsset INNER JOIN
>                            WorkOrder ON WorkManagementAsset.Oid = WorkOrder.Asset INNER JOIN
>                            WorkItem ON WorkOrder.Oid = WorkItem.WorkOrder INNER JOIN
>                            InspectionDefectItem ON WorkItem.DefectItem = InspectionDefectItem.Oid AND WorkItem.Oid = InspectionDefectItem.WorkItem
>   WHERE        (NOT (InspectionDefectItem.DefectGroupName LIKE N'Re%'))
>   GROUP BY WorkManagementAsset.AssetCategory, CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 120)
>   HAVING        (WorkManagementAsset.AssetCategory = N'sealedroads') AND (NOT (CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), 
>                            WorkItem.CompleteDate, 120) IS NULL))

The Query for T2:

> SELECT        WorkManagementAsset.AssetCategory, CONVERT(CHAR(4),
>   WorkItem.DueDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.DueDate, 120) AS
>   DueMonth, 
>                            COUNT(CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.DueDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.DueDate, 120)) AS Total_DUE FROM            WorkManagementAsset INNER JOIN
>                            WorkOrder ON WorkManagementAsset.Oid = WorkOrder.Asset INNER JOIN
>                            WorkItem ON WorkOrder.Oid = WorkItem.WorkOrder INNER JOIN
>                            InspectionDefectItem ON WorkItem.DefectItem = InspectionDefectItem.Oid AND WorkItem.Oid =
>   InspectionDefectItem.WorkItem WHERE        (NOT
>   (InspectionDefectItem.DefectGroupName LIKE N'Re%')) GROUP BY
>   WorkManagementAsset.AssetCategory, CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.DueDate,
>   100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.DueDate, 120) HAVING
>   (WorkManagementAsset.AssetCategory = N'sealedroads') AND
>   (CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.DueDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4),
>   WorkItem.DueDate, 120) <> '0')

Any help would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks

[Tables and Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2BnV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
WITH T1 AS
(
  SELECT 
    WorkManagementAsset.AssetCategory, 
    CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 120) AS CMonth, 
    COUNT(CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 120)) AS Total_Complete
  FROM WorkManagementAsset 
  INNER JOIN WorkOrder 
    ON WorkManagementAsset.Oid = WorkOrder.Asset 
  INNER JOIN WorkItem 
    ON WorkOrder.Oid = WorkItem.WorkOrder 
  INNER JOIN InspectionDefectItem 
    ON WorkItem.DefectItem = InspectionDefectItem.Oid AND WorkItem.Oid = InspectionDefectItem.WorkItem 
  WHERE (NOT (InspectionDefectItem.DefectGroupName LIKE N'Re%')) 
  GROUP BY 
    WorkManagementAsset.AssetCategory, 
    CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 120) 
  HAVING (WorkManagementAsset.AssetCategory = N'sealedroads') 
  AND (NOT (CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 120) IS NULL))
),
T2 AS
(
  SELECT 
    WorkManagementAsset.AssetCategory, 
    CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.DueDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.DueDate, 120) AS DueMonth, 
    COUNT(CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.DueDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.DueDate, 120)) AS Total_DUE 
  FROM WorkManagementAsset 
  INNER JOIN WorkOrder 
    ON WorkManagementAsset.Oid = WorkOrder.Asset 
  INNER JOIN WorkItem 
    ON WorkOrder.Oid = WorkItem.WorkOrder 
  INNER JOIN InspectionDefectItem 
    ON WorkItem.DefectItem = InspectionDefectItem.Oid 
    AND WorkItem.Oid = InspectionDefectItem.WorkItem 
  WHERE (NOT (InspectionDefectItem.DefectGroupName LIKE N'Re%')) 
  GROUP BY WorkManagementAsset.AssetCategory, 
  CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.DueDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.DueDate, 120) 
  HAVING (WorkManagementAsset.AssetCategory = N'sealedroads') 
  AND (CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.DueDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.DueDate, 120) <> '0')
)
SELECT *
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.CMonth = T2.DueMonth;
```

Note that this is a horrifically inefficient query for numerous reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and the query generates the desired output.Could you please indicate what are reasons of inefficiency, so that I can improve my knowledge and the query as well

Comment: @FazalT Curiosities like `AND (NOT (CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 120) IS NULL))` don't help. Wouldn't that be somewhat similar to `and WorkItem.CompleteDate is not NULL`?